# Compare two arrays and create two new arrays with missing and new elements using pure javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

How to compare two javascript arrays and create two new arrays of missing and new elements? Array elements will be always strings or numbers and it is not 100% sure that they will be sorted in any way.

```
var array1= ['11', '13', '14', '18', '22', '23', '25'];
var array2= ['11', '13', '15', '16', '17', '23', '25', '31'];
var missing_elements = [];
var new_elements = [];

***Required Output:***
missing_elements= ['14', '18', '22']
new_elements= ['15', '16', '17', '31']
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a simple solution is just to iterate over `array1`, testing the elements one at a time with [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to produce the list of missing elements, then do the reverse to get the list of new elements.

You could use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to keep it short:

```js
var array1= ['11', '13', '14', '18', '22', '23', '25'];
var array2= ['11', '13', '15', '16', '17', '23', '25', '31'];

var missing_elements = array1.filter(v => !array2.includes(v));
var new_elements = array2.filter(v => !array1.includes(v));

console.log(missing_elements);
console.log(new_elements);
```

Comment: Works well. But if array2 have duplicate values, then how to delete the duplicated value?
Eg: var array2= ['11', '13', '15', '16', '17', '23', '25', '31','17','11'];

Comment: Removing duplicates from arrays is covered in other questions, including one with [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/615754). You could combine one of those techniques with what I've shown, or do a separate `.filter()` before or afterwards.